# VSTO Create command for Outlook ribbon without adding to ribbon via add-in code?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

So super new at Outlook add-in's but I have created a VSTO add-in in C# for Outlook that is working. The function it does is triggered by a button on the ribbon which is added to the Add-Ins section on startup. I would prefer this not be added automatically by the add-in as it is now and instead be a command the user would add through the customize ribbon action in Outlook. I can use the customize ribbon function in Outlook to add this command to other ribbons and groups but so far have not figured out how to not add it to a ribbon through the add-in code and still have it available to customize.

Currently the button is created via XML not the ribbon designer. I have not included any code here since I'm not sure that any is needed for this question or what it would be if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `visible="false"` attribute to the button.

Comment: Thanks, I considered looking into that as an option but I do not want to even load it into the ribbon in the add-in code if possible since that would potentially add extra load time to add a new tab and button just to hide it. Also was not sure if that would hide/remove the tab if it was the only item and hidden. Also not sure what it might do if I have to hide the tab manually and other add-ins are added that use that tab as well since it is a default tab for add-ins.

Comment: Ribbon loading is instantaneous if your control is hidden. You cannot make a control available in Outlook unless it can somehow figure out it exists. And a ribbon is the only way to let it know.

Comment: interesting. Based on there being several buttons/controls in Outlook that are not on any ribbons by default I figured there must be a way to make them available without actually placing them on a ribbon to start. I did figure out a user can just hide the new ribbon and place the button anywhere they want after adding it so it's not as big an issue I guess.

Comment: Outlook is under no obligation to use the same API as the COM/VSTO addins. Some animals are more equal than others.

Comment: Tested adding this to the XML and it does hide the entire section and tab if it is the only button so marking this as the answer.
Example of the working XML:
<group id="ContentGroup" label="Custom">
 <button id="textButton" label="Send to Help Desk" size="large" image="HD_Dude" 
        visible="false" screentip="Send to helpdesk" onAction="OnTextButton" 
       supertip="Sends the selected email to the helpdesk ticket board with contact info for 
       original sender and deletes original email from your mailbox."/>
/group>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the `visible` attribute set to false you may consider using ribbon callbacks where you could set the visibility of your ribbon controls at runtime dynamically. So, you could keep settings for displaying ribbon controls depending on the user's preferences. The `getVisible` callback has the following signature (depending on your programming language):

```
C#: bool GetVisible(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)

C++: HRESULT GetVisible([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfVisible)

Visual Basic: Function GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

So, you just need to return an appropriate boolean value whether to display controls or not.

The `IRibbonUI.Invalidate` or `IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl` methods can help you update the ribbon controls at runtime (get your callbacks invoked and get updated values).